# Multidimensional Copula Simulation gives weird (auto correlated?) pattern

Tags: r, simulation

I am simulating from an 8-dimensional t-copula with df 8 and correlation between all dimensions of 0.1.

There are 3 different marginal types, the following marginals appear twice in the copula:

1. Normal distribution with mean 15 and sd 5 (col 1&2)
2. T-distribution with mean 0 and df 5 (col 7&8)

The following distribution appears four times in the 8-dimensional copula:

1. Normal distribution with mean 5 and sd 5 (col 3-6)

I specified all the parameters, defined the mvdc and drew 50 random variables several times with different seed numbers, and I always find this weird pattern, where col 1&2 is always high in the odd rows and low in the even rows. The relevant copula functions are as follows:

```
 myCop.t <- ellipCopula(family = "t", dim = dim, dispstr = "toep", param = copcor, df = df)

        multi.distr <- mvdc(myCop.t, distrvec, paravec, marginsIdentical = FALSE,
                            check = FALSE, fixupNames = TRUE)

        randoms <- rMvdc(50, multi.distr)
```

The respective arguments within the copula function provide the correct parameters and are therefore not of interest here, and I strongly suspect that the actual code is not of interest here at all.

The data output looks like this:

```
        V1      V2       V3       V4       V5       V6          V7           V8
1  16.010861 14.996232 5.701437 6.787819 5.475126 6.990366  1.69338912  2.666378900
2   7.014132  5.563823 6.515101 4.660104 5.957121 6.781011  0.86962636  2.034051794
3  15.672679 15.749123 6.239703 5.087319 5.661866 5.419313 -0.03725051  0.115770530
4   4.323271  7.001562 5.941222 6.291748 4.793068 5.752201  2.03728897  1.857472281
5  14.368017 16.878522 4.601959 4.832871 4.713307 5.335259 -0.65059333 -0.006805472
6   6.407364  4.536828 5.434258 5.716145 5.054762 5.886708  0.76146941  0.662944596
7  15.323959 13.996845 4.740232 6.051559 3.994886 3.556641 -1.00196874  1.034595276
8   3.739731  5.284797 5.137518 5.345029 4.224926 5.133985  0.60952885  0.232399508
9  16.092425 15.895005 6.255278 6.480924 5.283971 4.965157  0.97320818  0.516121522
10  4.333453  5.208740 5.074339 5.606373 4.489304 5.094264  1.04653615 -0.055464950
11 15.211897 16.096414 6.372798 5.259175 6.041479 4.722053 -0.30172391 -0.199618446
12  5.851663  4.997275 6.050953 4.413398 5.323346 5.326618  1.07938868  1.115312951
13 15.815942 15.572386 5.463940 6.088293 5.670306 5.300775  1.56742392  0.686777736
14  4.446224  4.163309 4.181659 4.777350 4.568136 4.213055 -0.72199878 -0.824398248
15 14.785817 16.274832 5.669137 5.589509 4.655658 5.689984  0.19452841  1.349848277
16  4.109499  4.473835 3.919780 3.214149 4.263928 5.531912 -1.11236543 -1.303189568
17 14.239574 13.276767 4.200647 4.781725 4.326090 4.338101  0.70853038 -0.156449752
18  6.898483  6.994064 7.815153 6.462504 5.877854 5.384026  1.29072261  0.293196041
19 15.412930 15.349961 5.018926 5.922361 5.125757 6.700596 -1.12301994 -0.399204202
20  5.079742  4.748265 5.457855 4.654723 4.731529 4.188034 -0.34238254 -0.690145740
21 14.141139 13.888448 3.855420 4.827962 4.275877 3.921048 -0.70280816 -1.123617466
22  5.379309  6.428976 6.218161 4.924798 6.039379 5.474278 -0.05402753  0.808884618
23 15.810009 16.474434 4.722685 6.654449 5.799382 5.148503  0.21074129 -2.691441462
24  4.504196  4.134488 6.133392 5.341009 4.146695 5.485827 -0.17429215  0.377224880
25 15.090372 18.562274 6.940438 8.702905 7.421064 7.234131  0.95681780 13.957746201
26  5.169069  4.689696 3.945228 3.831344 4.257807 4.485700 -1.25036470 -1.015452283
27 14.231269 14.573801 3.979783 3.975574 4.059549 3.429011 -0.84782089 -0.708102232
28  3.466399  4.809140 4.642554 4.000181 5.514467 3.702483 -0.28220028 -2.230534184
29 14.535945 15.068252 5.389390 3.925671 4.820220 5.385509  0.44983724  0.369502404
30  5.721859  6.277543 4.951993 6.146136 5.522600 5.546753  2.97382789 -0.285541576
31 14.032321 14.633016 6.217122 3.954871 5.537166 6.034675  1.20169471 -0.023094229
32  4.866420  4.272465 3.896341 5.120164 3.583863 4.909106 -0.06676720 -0.296015677
33 14.833177 15.180053 4.989203 4.202957 4.889351 5.098410 -3.42600028  0.538323743
34  4.611121  4.268716 4.238652 3.660678 3.547858 4.580510 -1.77435703 -1.665450739
35 14.528331 13.893190 5.167363 4.361532 4.512446 4.611733 -1.85922632 -0.082607647
36  4.388169  4.139480 5.073937 5.257833 4.617510 4.309536 -0.97743122 -0.813389458
37 16.048187 17.595425 6.047185 5.723189 5.221158 5.160128  0.83381764  0.479124155
38  6.132494  4.633051 5.682781 5.747092 5.825939 5.104212 -0.07316043  1.717729460
39 15.559974 14.191118 6.874427 6.107418 6.731673 5.141445  0.10187992  0.351784075
40  5.126939  4.776856 5.626305 5.688585 6.054434 4.635697  0.68777501  0.653913128
41 14.687924 13.981411 5.854028 3.827776 3.636622 4.875557 -3.74749849 -1.843810747
42  4.632315  4.789424 5.133586 4.137874 5.002943 4.692032  0.67748217 -0.410707115
43 15.128650 16.278525 4.222412 3.912493 4.496541 3.582153  2.61045652  0.319884730
44  3.808546  5.055248 4.049429 4.836402 4.626999 4.031213 -1.70918390 -0.074491627
45 13.928535 13.631071 3.207690 3.501214 3.869997 3.519227 -2.32473887 -0.374699516
46  5.291424  5.473507 5.206400 4.055007 5.063000 4.069546  0.88998427 -0.055496756
47 15.596255 15.095043 4.619923 5.180290 5.550825 5.968506  2.15353841  0.063891460
48  6.471105  5.759449 5.731538 5.544783 5.612262 5.214522  1.15215748  0.607186739
49 15.159832 15.716472 4.666025 5.146686 5.394190 5.999513  1.27856163 -0.191519256
50  3.826062  4.010362 4.285219 3.725003 4.648102 3.732760 -0.54854635 -0.721668612
```

The really weird thing is that when I change the parameters of the normal distribution in column 1 and 2, so that the mean of the normal distribution is still 15, but the sd is 15 as well (up from 5 before) the data appear to be "right" again, with no pattern between the rows. Sample Output of that simulations is as follows:

```
         V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6           V7          V8
1  14.83778 15.50690 5.404255 6.529869 3.723583 5.804804 -0.023806934  1.31729448
2  14.89108 15.52742 4.546552 4.133864 3.798082 3.944486 -0.958503275 -0.25154357
3  15.18946 14.42179 3.942194 5.375967 5.513438 5.338239 -0.941209336  1.02601868
4  13.89376 15.06167 5.741713 4.913896 4.800117 6.500235 -0.221074057 -0.32954484
5  15.25007 14.58085 4.518882 5.137600 4.328629 5.634427 -0.934152880 -1.50506026
6  17.57606 16.87651 6.309456 4.743752 4.066471 5.642209  0.777167206 -0.22662543
7  17.08080 12.29113 6.133664 5.059785 5.264676 4.733923 -0.219459993 -1.12209908
8  15.93970 14.43690 4.057061 5.064182 5.326703 5.564106 -1.250717314  0.94948212
9  16.24507 14.48802 4.975028 5.761803 6.711075 4.221429 -1.024120847 -0.33025094
10 15.47580 14.91176 4.118495 4.555365 5.210769 5.204387  0.829185436 -0.04127958
11 13.50148 16.05232 5.492861 4.048113 5.125046 6.086061  0.167497301 -1.17138922
12 14.30186 15.19833 5.076858 3.775417 5.300832 5.992216  0.164344390  0.68483847
13 15.91798 14.47786 3.007620 6.224872 3.830338 3.028243 -0.071242353  0.81984925
14 17.41911 14.49935 5.013210 5.169754 5.544124 5.201758  0.338119344 -0.35646076
15 15.76726 13.03769 3.462312 5.094576 6.251835 5.644511  0.071842820 -2.48345545
16 14.99288 14.54641 5.733469 6.241158 6.111138 4.372109 -1.002280884  0.76748645
17 15.17871 14.88004 6.631951 4.846311 6.077040 4.385127 -0.699274238 -1.84938212
18 12.90336 15.18397 4.481494 6.204927 3.310052 2.046945 -1.842346138 -0.46791915
19 14.31310 14.32862 6.963597 5.853332 4.124151 4.093026 -1.662460882 -0.27031668
20 17.25331 16.73606 4.674062 5.949045 5.169811 4.856738  0.048013929  1.07306298
21 15.38818 13.76637 4.897191 5.626547 5.076134 5.823196  0.137200385  1.40611275
22 15.35279 16.89325 5.150686 4.490542 3.409013 5.184520  0.004938741 -1.45164671
23 15.88499 15.31334 5.260789 4.401654 4.452729 6.435039  0.789386209 -0.50842299
24 16.06672 14.82119 5.024210 4.587017 5.758393 5.662651  0.231251570 -0.12430524
25 14.93408 15.62573 3.730154 3.625504 4.775070 3.788278  0.830299184  0.97256207
26 16.20754 14.23117 4.843946 4.206059 3.778496 3.346761  1.614550837 -1.75024630
27 16.71283 11.65426 3.559865 4.701199 4.198006 6.891123 -0.454631494 -0.42152501
28 15.15844 13.94274 4.657491 6.611439 6.503309 5.580698  1.133942406  0.44039104
29 14.26423 15.83374 5.961393 5.223553 5.173916 4.709981  1.424424855 -0.43280752
30 15.67209 15.29075 5.740236 4.233706 5.582893 4.706259  1.572087272  0.38300052
31 14.21829 14.83687 4.442544 5.778498 4.822692 6.121222 -0.318373779 -0.27456086
32 14.98008 14.26653 5.844600 4.832860 4.213410 5.809996 -1.779622235  0.07399854
33 15.63392 15.19140 5.263267 5.305941 5.929871 5.175858  0.086394088 -0.34753023
34 13.75393 14.16023 3.510472 5.739289 3.397409 5.158956 -0.378902314 -0.45783589
35 15.87641 13.69308 4.151437 5.504838 4.602269 4.988841 -0.618535468 -1.13646497
36 14.95559 15.79736 4.811952 5.113602 5.195094 4.568496  0.010490101 -1.01004477
37 13.83409 13.25046 6.686703 3.514009 5.308698 7.868867  9.791588382  2.05239012
38 15.60604 14.11555 6.362565 5.440548 5.503359 5.640982 -0.111587857 -0.39176421
39 15.96660 14.28885 5.726868 5.199140 5.990608 4.585727  1.768536285 -0.08786540
40 15.65997 16.64071 5.274348 5.406443 3.618235 7.037277 -2.381014003  0.38575367
41 14.18519 16.27092 4.780902 4.313851 5.706422 5.786148  0.024784912 -1.41593055
42 14.97552 12.97847 4.106621 5.258110 5.112121 5.313409  0.553056422  2.90330487
43 16.29216 16.30951 6.591961 5.021240 6.155636 3.628142 -1.787351964 -0.08872408
44 13.83075 14.44732 4.561066 5.177443 4.070881 5.955008 -1.050899776  0.89126680
45 14.44366 15.77155 6.323065 5.218095 3.199359 5.855317 -0.452537507  0.20151892
46 13.96975 15.67864 4.051353 5.602012 4.278524 4.870577  0.304695524  0.06143125
47 13.64975 13.30919 3.409978 7.107219 2.358819 5.178817 -0.486368335 -2.70001802
48 17.67098 15.15840 4.435062 6.742152 4.131794 5.817331 -1.161750029  0.31463652
49 15.62723 14.95017 5.157411 6.137096 4.993191 5.129493 -0.058337660  1.18703728
50 14.39389 13.07334 5.234347 3.257008 3.612170 4.721898  1.070309092 -0.59448545
```

So what is going here? In the original example, the first two columns had a, compared to the other two marginal types, low standard deviation, while in the second one all normal distributions had the same std as their mean. Is this an inherent feature of multidimensional copulas where the marginals have, relatively speaking, quite different volatilities, or is maybe the underlying algorithm of the copula package not exact?